# How to lock an Azure web app down to a specific group of users

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

This should really be a basic question, but I can't find the answer anywhere.

I've got a website that I'm hosting as an Azure Web App. I've created an App Registration and I've associated the Web App with the App. Now, I'm prompted to log on before being allowed to view the web site. So far so good, but I want to lock it down so that only a specific group of users has access to the site.

I go to Enterprise Applications and I give permission the application to certain users/groups. But I can still log into the website as any user in the tenancy.

How do I ensure that only a certain group of users can log into the website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you've discovered how to assign users and groups to the app (under Enterprise apps, in the Azure portal). These assignments are called "app role assignments". As you've also noticed, by default, app role assignment is *not* required in order for users to be able to sign in. However, there *is* a configuration which you can use to *require* an app role assignment.

In the Azure portal, under Azure Active Directory > Enterprise apps > (choose your app) > Properties:

[image: Require user assignment for an Enterprise app]

(Note: Sometimes it takes a few seconds for this option to appear, when you load the Properties blade.)

And if you want to do the same thing with Azure AD PowerShell, you could do something like this:

```bsh
$appId = "{the app ID}"
$servicePrincipal = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "appId eq '$appId'"
Set-AzureADServicePrincipal -ObjectId $servicePrincipal.ObjectId `
                            -AppRoleAssignmentRequired $true
```

Comment: Now that's the magic sauce I was missing! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Azure Websites integrates with the Role-Based Access Control (RBAC) feature. Enabling RBAC gives you greater control over whom you allow access to your resources and what level of access each person has.

Goto your app -> Access Control (IAM) -> assign roles.

**Owner** - Has full admin access to the site and can perform all operations.

**Contributor** – Can deploy code, start/stop the site, swap deployments, delete the site, etc. Cannot change pricing plan or perform some other admin functions.

**Reader** – Can view the website in the portal, but cannot make any changes to it.

For more details, refer [Managing User Access to Specific Sites in the Azure Portal](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2015/01/07/managing-user-access-to-specific-sites-in-the-azure-portal/) and [Use Role-Based Access Control to manage access to your Azure subscription resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-configure).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it doesn't really answer the question. I'm not trying to restrict access to the website from the portal. Instead I want to restrict the users who can access the website itself. I would like everyone who navigates to the website's URL to have to log on, and only a specific group of users will be able to use the website.

Comment: Then i suggest you use Authentication/authorization feature to restrict access to specific users. Refer this for more details: https://msftplayground.com/2017/06/restricting-access-to-your-azure-web-application/